# Excel Formula LEN and Subtitute

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So i have Image URLs that i need to split.

I tried this Formula

```
=RIGHT(N2,LEN(N2)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(N2,"/","|",LEN(N2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(N2,"/","")))))
```

and it removed whole URL and just leaving the Image file name.

**Example when i used the Formula:**
**Image URL**
domain.com/images/products/72/252/19795/3/279/image-name.jpg

**Result after using the formula**
image-name.jpg

The thing is i need to get the /279/ on the Result. So the result will looks like /279/image-name.jpg

What i need to change on the Formula that i used to also leave the /279/ text on the result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1)),LEN(A1))
```

Where we would first `SUBSTITUTE()` the second to last forward slash into a pipe. Then we `FIND()` it's postition and take the substring through `MID()`.

A fun alternative is to split the string by its forward slash as a delimiter and join back the last two substrings:

```
=CONCAT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>/")&"</s></t>","//s[position()>last()-2]"))
```

Comment: What about getting the result Backwards without using split and didnt include the /279/ text with Formula ?

Comment: What do you mean@rullymnh? If it's a new quesiton maybe consider to open a new question and explain what it is you are after.